# How to virtualize/sandbox windows games to simulate inputs for each individually?

Tags: design

We are working on a game streaming product in a startup which works really well in its current state. Games can be played over the internet with very low latency on client application.

Now there are multiple ways to make the system work for large number of users. First, Virtual Machines, i.e. one Windows VM for each connected client running one single game in full screen and then optimize the resources used be VMs. Input simulation is easier ([`SendInput`](https://serverfault.com/questions/767290/auto-login-multiple-users-on-windows-server-2012) for most games).

Second, the current way, is to run multiple games (each played by a different user) in windowed mode providing each game a sandbox. Simulating input in this case is the [real problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35408495/sendinput-to-background-window). Games can be using any and all of Window Messages, Direct Input, Raw Input or any other way to get input from devices. It works only for some games but [not always possible](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513) to simulate input on each game process. It is messy.

Third, Windows Server sessions, which we are [unable to configure](https://serverfault.com/questions/767290/auto-login-multiple-users-on-windows-server-2012) for multiple users. Multiple users will be given game stream from their individual sessions. As each game is running in its own standalone windows environment, input simulation is easier.

Nvidia provides API for both full-screen capture and DirectX, OpenGL capture of individual applications. They suggested to run games/apps in sandbox so they do not interfere. Input simulation was the biggest hurdle here so we tried sessions in windows server. But to keep each session alive, RDP must remain connected.

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/767290/auto-login-multiple-users-on-windows-server-2012) was closed on SF and SO was too angry so I deleted it. So my question is what would be the best way to virtualize the game application in a way that all games on OS receives input individually without interfering with another?

Comment: It seems you are asking us how to design your company's new product ... I can't really see why would anyone, if they had a solution, disclose this information (because it indeed looks like something complicated AND valuable AND patentable AND ...)

Comment: @Tibo I was suggested/encouraged to ask it here http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28918182#28918182

Comment: Updated the question title and question.